# Angular 2 + .Net Core Web Application (.Net Framework 4.5.2) node_modules scripts not found

Tags: asp.net, node.js, asp.net-mvc, angular, src

I have prject on Core(.Net Framework 4.5.2) template and angular 2 app.
When i used Core 1.0 there were no problems, but i need Core(.Net Framework 4.5.2).

[Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMb9R.jpg)

When i try use npm scripts in .cshtml i get error, that files not foud.
Please Help!!!
[script with node_modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhRvH.jpg)

If i use MVC usual .NET 452 template such problems were not

If you can please contact with me for more details...
llotall7@gmail.com

Comment: What is in your node_modules folder? have you installed those packages?

Comment: @Arcath Yes this is npm packages folder.

Comment: @Arcath if interested you can try create SPA with this temlate like me, and you will understand problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your MVC app is likely not configured to expose that folder publicly, you typically would use a build step to bundle the needed code from your `node_modules` folder out into your dist folder.

In the case of using SystemJS (which seems to be outdated, by the way) you might add a task in your build process to copy those folders over to your dist folder.

If you're interested in moving away from SystemJS, I'd highly recommend that you take a look at the Angular CLI. It makes setup a breeze, and is supported by the Angular core team.

Comment: Please take me example, i will so gladfull!